# What is the best practice for a multiple request at same time

Tags: android

I have to send four different request in an api at the same time. Do i need to make AsyncTask background thread for each request or all request could be done through a single AsyncTask. Can somebody please help.

Comment: separate async task for everyone

Comment: you could consider using a networklib like Volley to take care of multiple async requests for you, without making your code unnecessary complex

Comment: @VivekMishra this is almost certainly not true. I am going to look up exactly how this works in Java and try to post an answer but HTTP, in particular HTTP/2, has a lot of ways for simplifying the process of making multiple requests.

Comment: Hi, i think u can try with **Retrofit** library http://square.github.io/retrofit/ , it very useful for client/server app

Comment: @WilliamRosenbloom can i get any idea how can it be done.

Comment: I'm writing an answer now.

Comment: thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a concurrency issue. There is literally dozens of ways to do this in Android. I've written almost every single one for courses that cover this material... and even then it isn't 'simple'.

I'd personally make use of HaMeR (Handler, Messages, Runnable) framework of Android. Create 4 runnables and have them post their results to a Handler.

However... That isn't the easiest to implement. and would require you to understand how to safely create your own custom handler (making use of WeakReference properly, etc.)

Therefore, I'd recommend running the asyncTask(s) on the executorService

`myTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);` The default thread pool executor should start with 4 threads (I believe off-hand without looking it up).

Comment: I agree with the using ThreadPoolExecutor. I have used it for one of my recent project. It does your truly independent tasks in fraction of seconds provided there are no blocking calls like conn.getResponseCode().

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using HttpURLConnections. Unfortunately each of those connections, as specified in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), is capable of handling only a single request.

However, you can (and possibly should) still perform all your requests in a single AsyncTask. **Each AsyncTask will require the creation of a new thread which takes lots of time and resources.** So don't listen to anyone who tells you to create a new task for each request.

You also have the option of exploiting HTTP persistence. If you add the header `Connection: Keep-Alive` to your request via `connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");`, you will be able to send multiple requests over the same connection and save a lot of time and resources.

It's a little complicated in Java, because of the one-request-per-httpurlconnection rule, but it can be done. First, when you are done with your first request's HttpURLConnection **do not close that connection**. Then, to create the next connection, call `url.openConnection()` on **the same URL object** that you used to create your first HttpURLConnection. The JVM will know to reuse that connection if possible to save bandwidth.

You also have the option of using HTTP/2.0 multiplexing, which allows you to send multiple requests literally at the same time. Unfortunately I am not yet well versed enough in HTTP/2.0 to tell you exactly how to make use of this, but the multiplexing feature was included to solve exactly this problem.